# C#: Запуск Tasks в цикле

Tags: c#, task, асинхронность

Код:

```
    Task<RequestBodyModelDC>[] relatedObjectMapping = new Task<RequestBodyModelDC>[fields.Columns.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < relatedObjectMapping.Count(); i++)
    {
        Task<RequestBodyModelDC> currTask = new Task<RequestBodyModelDC>(() =>
        {
            return FillMappingObkect(i, fields, entity);
        });

        relatedObjectMapping[i] = currTask;
        relatedObjectMapping[i].Start();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что в currTask каждый раз попадают **последние данные** из коллекции relatedObjectMapping, соответственно идет дублирование данных.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так,чтобы в цикле при создании Таски в нее передавались актуальное значение параметра "i" в функцию FillMappingObkect!**

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в захвате переменной. Просто создайте переменную с ограниченной областью видимости и на каждой итерации цикла она будет своя:

```
for (int i = 0; i < relatedObjectMapping.Count(); i++)
{
    int localI = i;
    // Дальше везде используем localI вместо i
```

Comment: Описать, что такое "захват переменной" - вот вам и будет эталонная закрывашка ;)